# displaying data from fetch api using react

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I am developing a simple website which displays data from an API(JSON) into a page using react.

I'm using the fetch() API.

I am able to get the data from the API and set it into the 'App' component state but I'm not able to pass is down to Table and Row components that I've manually created.

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {ticker: {}, volume: {}}
    this.loadData = this.loadData.bind(this)
    this.loadData()
  }

  loadData () {
    fetch(ticker)
          .then((resp) => resp.json())
          .then((data) => {

            this.setState({
              ticker: data
            })
          })
          .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err)
          })
    fetch(volume)
          .then((resp) => resp.json())
          .then((data) => {

            this.setState({
              volume: data
            })
          })
            .catch((err) => {
              console.log(err)
            })
  }


  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        <Navbar />
        <div className='container'>
          <div className='align'>
            <div className='element' />

          </div>
          <Table volume={this.state.volume} ticker={this.state.ticker} />

        </div>
      </div>

    )
  }
}
```

BOTTOM LINE:
I have an API with data, and I have 3 components, Table, which also has a row component.
I want to display variables in the Row component
which looks like this

```
<Row img='eth' name='Ethereum' price='' volume='' change='' marketCap='' />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You constructor :

```
constructor (props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {ticker: {}, volume: {}}
    this.loadData = this.loadData.bind(this);
  }
```

For fetching data you need always to use lifecycle component, as `componentDidMount` or `componentWillMount`, thus :

```
componentDidMount(){
   this.loadData()
}
```

And then in your state you will have the data.

In your `render` method pass it as props to the `Table` component:

```
render(){
   return(
      <Table volume={this.state.volume} ticker={this.state.ticker} />
   )
}
```

Then in from the `Table` component pass it to `Row` component as props, thus :

```
render(){
   return(
     <Row img='eth' name='Ethereum' price='' volume={this.props.volume} change='' marketCap='' />
   )
}
```

If you have array of objects, something like :

```
this.state = {
    volume: [ {name: "One", size: 1 }, {name: "Two", size: 2 }, ..... ]
}
```

You'll need to loop through the array and show the `Row` component for each object.

Thus, your `Table` component should be something as follows:

```
render(){
   return (
       <div>{this.props.volume.map(vol => <Row img='eth' name='Ethereum' price='' volume={vol} change='' marketCap='' />)  }</div>
   ) 
}
```

Comment: Thanks! We are now manipulating the data into an array so we can map them.

Answer (score 0):

If you make the ajax call in `componentDidMount`, then React will rerender when the state changes (https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount). But you still have to anticipate that the `volume` and `ticker` props will be empty until the request resolves and React rerenders.

Comment: Yeah, thats exactly whats happening I guess. How do I make the data render once the fetch is completed?

Comment: Call `loadData` from `componentDidMount`. React will rerender on state change.

Comment: How do I pass down the state into a sub component?

Comment: The way you're doing it: `<Table volume={this.state.volume} ticker={this.state.ticker} />`

Comment: Oh, but I also have a Row component that needs to use the state inside of the Table component. That is unable to access the data

Comment: Yeah but I have a 'Row' component which needs to access it

Comment: So inside the `Table` component, you'll have access to `volume` and `ticker` as props. Just pass them down to the row component: `<Row img='eth' name='Ethereum' price='' volume={this.props.volume} change='' marketCap='' />`